# CSS to have fluid layout multi-column grid where each div varies in height

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I want to make a layout that consists of 3 columns. The 3 columns are made up of `div`s that each contain an image of variable aspect ratio. I want to stack these multiple-height divs in the 3 columns in such a way that the gap (margin) between them is equal vertically and horizontally. There should be no margin/padding on the outside; i.e. the 3 columns should span the 100% of the container.

Here is an example:

[image]

On a smaller screen I would have the 3 columns collapse into just 1 and have all the divs vertically stacked.

[In my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVrhN/) we can see I have used `column-count` to have the 3 columns. My problem is setting the `column-width` and `margin-bottom` to be a consistent value where they create the same gap: 1.5% of the container width.

Here is the CSS I used. `.container` houses the many `.tile` divs which in turn each hold an image of unknown dimensions. The number of child `divs` is also unknown.

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1.5%;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5%;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5%;
    border:1px black solid;
}
.tile {
    margin-bottom:9%;
}
.tile img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/130" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/125" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/50" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/150" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I set the spacing between each div (both horizontally and vertically) to be a fluid value?

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap for this? [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Wait are you saying you want gap to set space between the single-col version and the edges? Gap won't do that for you.

Comment: Perhaps not answer-worthy but I ended up using [JQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for this problem. Yes, it uses jquery/js instead of pure css but it's pretty lightweight and works well.